# In Magento how to show invoice no.?

Tags: php, magento, invoice

I want to show invoice no. in a page what is the code for insert invoice no. for particular order and show particular invoice no. there is any way to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderid);
if ($order->hasInvoices()) { // check if order has invoice
    foreach ($order->getInvoiceCollection() as $inv) {
        $invIncrementIDs[] = $inv->getIncrementId();
    //other invoice details...
    } 
  print_r($invIncrementIDs);
}
```

I think this might help you